# What is the meaning of 'leisurely vengeance' in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

He looked around and added: “That goes for your shadow-loving fleabag partner, too, wherever he’s hiding.” 
 The Weasel stepped up to the horse and peered at the disheveled figure.

“Why, it’s Rincewind the wizard, isn’t it?” he said in tones of delight, meanwhile filing the wizard’s description of him in his memory for **leisurely** **vengeance**. “I thought I recognized the voice.”

(Page 9). 
 This is an exerpt from Terry practchett 'The color of magic'.

Comment: also ,I want to ask  if all readers (principally, natives) usually skip over phrases that they do not understand or they do make an attempt at finding its meaning or they simply, generally understand everything

Comment: Some of us resort to leisurely consultation of a dictionary, while others look the phrase up immediately so that we can understand and follow along, while yet others are content to remain ignorant.

Comment: Also, it depends on the writer.  I generally skip over and try to find meaning in context via a background mental process when I come across unfamiliar terminology, though I will go to a dictionary if necessary.  With an author like Terry Pratchett - who enjoys word play, puns and other linguistic hi-jinks - however, I spend time trying to tease out the meaning as there's usually a chuckle to be had when you do.

Answer (score 2):

It would mean "vengeance which he intends to take when the time is convenient for him", that is, at his leisure. He is in no rush.  **leisurely vengeance** is not a common collocation, but this usage of **leisurely** is quite common.

> They strolled along  at a leisurely pace.